How to filter only active layers in QgsMapLayerComboBox
I'm filtering the layers in a QgsMapLayerComboBox and in addition to filtering according to geometry, I want to remove the layers that are disabled? Is it possible? How do I do it? I'm using the following code to filter according to geometry.
self.CMBNODES.setFilters(QgsMapLayerProxyModel.PointLayer)
self.CMBPIPES.setFilters(QgsMapLayerProxyModel.LineLayer)
self.CMBMDE.setFilters(QgsMapLayerProxyModel.RasterLayer )
self.CMBCURVAS.setFilters(QgsMapLayerProxyModel.NoGeometry)


By 'disabled', do you mean their visibility is checked off?

Yes, I can get a list of the layers that are in QGIS and a list of which are active/enabled.
layers_enableds = self.iface.mapCanvas().layers() <><><>
layers = QgsProject.instance().mapLayers().values()

QgsMapLayerComboBox has a setExceptedLayerList() method which you can pass a list of layers which you want to exclude from being shown in the combo box. https://api.qgis.org/api/classQgsMapLayerComboBox.html#a971f6710119167497816a255813bf17f

Use the setExceptedLayerList() method of QgsMapLayerComboBox. You can pass this method a list of layers which want to exclude from being shown in the combo box. You will probably want to run this logic in a method which is also connected to the QgsMapCanvas.layersChanged signal.
Simple example below:
class TestDialog(QDialog):
    def __init__(self):
        super(TestDialog, self).__init__()
        self.canvas = iface.mapCanvas()
        self.setGeometry(300, 300, 500, 200)
        self.mlcb = QgsMapLayerComboBox(self)
        self.layout = QVBoxLayout(self)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.mlcb)
        self.filter_layers()
        self.canvas.layersChanged.connect(self.filter_layers)
        
    def filter_layers(self):
        checked_layers = self.canvas.layers()
        excluded_layers = [l for l in QgsProject.instance().mapLayers().values() if not l in checked_layers]
        self.mlcb.setExceptedLayerList(excluded_layers)
        
dlg = TestDialog()
dlg.show()

